# Use variable as an argument inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very bad in programming...

I have a javascript variable

```
var a = 'S_QEEFCEAPU';
```

Then there is another html like this

```
<a href="#" onClick='jQuery("#youtube-player-container").tubeplayer("play","S_QEEFCEAPU")'>Video 1</a>
```

I want to use the variable name instead of the string S_QEEFCEAPU in tubeplayer function call. How can I do it?

Comment: `tubeplayer("play",a)` should work if you variable is declared in the global scope.

Comment: why are you putting jquery inside an attribute? this is smelly.

Comment: @dystroy: That is actually an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a javascript function for on click of your link and using the javascript variable there.,

**In html**

```
<a href="#" onClick='yourFunction()'>Video 1</a>
```

**In javascript**

```
function yourFunction(){
     var a = 'S_QEEFCEAPU';
    jQuery("#youtube-player-container").tubeplayer("play",a)
}
```

If `a` is defined out side function and `global scope`

```
 var a = 'S_QEEFCEAPU';
function yourFunction(){      
    jQuery("#youtube-player-container").tubeplayer("play",a)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do this if the variable is in the global scope -

```
<a href="#" onClick='jQuery("#youtube-player-container").tubeplayer("play", a)'>Video 1</a>
```

I recommend that you give your variables better names though. And using unobtrusive JavaScript to get away from onClick's. And not putting jQuery statements in onClick's.